# how to display search term in the template full site editor

Tags: wordpress, templates

i am building a template for the search page (in full site editing, therefore html and no php), and i want to have a search results heading. i have this:

```
 <!-- wp:group {"layout":{"inherit":true}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group">
<!-- wp:heading {"level":1} -->
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<!-- /wp:heading -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->
```

now i have 2 issues:

1- how do i get the search term to display it?

2- how can i translate the "Search Results" string?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the search term is not possible to do yet using WordPress core blocks.

To make any text translatable, you can put the text inside a block pattern.
Then include that pattern inside the template with the pattern block:

```
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":"themeslug/pattern-name"} /-->
```